# Thunks in React-Redux - Not Resolving?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using React and Redux to create a login system with Google Firebase. I am trying to understand how to use thunks. I am calling my action `createUser` from my React component however, I'm not able to handle the callback successfully.

Here is the component function I am calling the action from:

```
registerUser() {
    let email = this.state.user.email;
    let pw= this.state.user.password;

    this.props.actions.createUser(email, pw)
        .then((user) => {
            debugger; // The async request is successful but execution doesn't pause here
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            debugger; // Instead I receive an error here that says, "Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
        });
}
```

Here are the actions:

```
export function createUserSuccess(user) {
    debugger;
    return { type: types.CREATE_USER_SUCCESS, payload: { registeredUser: user, registerMsg: 'Successful Registration!'  }};
}

export function createUserError(error) {
    return { type: types.CREATE_USER_ERROR, payload: { registeredUser: {}, registerMsg: error.message }};
}


export function createUser(email, pw) { // async thunk
    debugger;
    return (dispatch) => {
        debugger;
        return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
            .then((user) => {dispatch(createUserSuccess(user))}) // todo: figure out why this won't resolve
            .catch(error => dispatch(createUserError(error)));
    }
}
```

And my Reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function registerReducer(state = initialState.registeredUser, action) {
debugger;
switch (action.type) {
    case types.CREATE_USER_SUCCESS:
        return [
            ...state, // es6 spread operator - explodes all values in array
            Object.assign({}, action.payload)
        ];

    case types.CREATE_USER_ERROR:
        return [
            ...state,
            Object.assign({}, action.payload)
        ];

    default:
        return state;
  }
```

}

I know the actual request to Google firebase is OK because the `createUserSuccess` action creator gets fired. Why isn't execution stopping at the appropriate place in my React Component?

Comment: Can you update your container here?

Comment: If an error is caught in the catch callback, after `createUserSuccess(user)` have been called, there might be something in that function or your reducer that throws an exception. Could you share your reducer code?

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen I thought so too but I couldn't find anything wrong with my reducer code. I added it above.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see anything wrong either. I trust it's on purpose your state is an array instead of an object? What does the error say when it's caught?

Answer (score 0):

You can check here this implementation

- The Service when we read the user auth and set the value to Redux
  https://github.com/x-team/unleash/blob/develop/app/services/authService.js
- The reducer when set the user state to the redux state object
  https://github.com/x-team/unleash/blob/develop/app/reducers/userReducer.js
- The action creators
  https://github.com/x-team/unleash/blob/develop/app/actions/UserActions.js

The most important part is the authService, let me know any question